# piecewise linear function

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I have a problem. I want to approximate $|x|$ on $[-1,1]$ by a sequence of functions $f_n\in C^1([-1,1])$ uniformly convergent to $|x|$. My very desire is to find such sequence, that $f'_n$ converges to Heaviside function. Is it possible? If it is, how to do it?

Comment: On $[0,1]$, you have $\lvert x\rvert = x$. What precisely do you want to do?

Comment: No, I mean on $[-1,1]$. Sorry :(